# Not able to retrieve a single value from php array

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, pdo

We have a  Stored Procedure in MSSQL that returns two values:

```
Agent | Tickets
int   | int
```

We are successfully connecting to the database server and calling the SP with pdo like this:

```
<?php 
//Declare hostname variable
$hostname = 'servername';

try {
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$hostname;Database=dbnamee");
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$agent = 249;
$stmt = $conn->prepare("{CALL Proc_GetActiveTicketsForAgent (:agent)}");
$stmt->bindParam(":agent",$agent, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$results = array();
do {
$results []= $stmt->fetchAll();
} while ($stmt->nextRowset());

echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);echo "\n"; // all record sets
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

This outputs the full array (as a test).

What I am trying to do is returning the value of Tickets (for example; 6, which is the current number of tickets on agent 249), and I can do this by using:

```
$results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
print($results->Tickets);
```

When I go to our index site, and use the include() function, I can output the whole array (this is just a part of the code):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>sitetitle</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php include('phpfile.php');

?>
<p>
<?php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);echo "\n"; // all record sets
echo '</pre>';
?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I try to use the same function as earlier:

```
print($results->Tickets);
```

I get "500 - internal server error"

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? I am starting to go bald from pulling my hair out.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use a foreach loop with your fetchAll statement. I placed it in the answer section below for better formatting.

Comment: print the output of $resuts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this after your execute statement:

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll()
```

Then to loop through the results:

```
foreach($results as $row){
    echo $row['Agent']. ": ". $row['Tickets'];
}
```

Comment: Something so simple, yet works perfectly. Seems like I was over-thinking this. Thank you, @kojow7

Comment: No worries, I do that too! :)